# RXJS operators are not functions

Tags: vue.js, rxjs, observable

I am getting this error when I try to use rxjs in vue using vue-rx with rxjs.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: messageObservable.fromEvent(...).map(...).debounceTime is not a function"
```

I do not see any wrong imports from the documentation that I looked at and I am not getting any build errors when building the JS on my dev enviroment.

THese are the imports that I have

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
```

This is the fucntions calling these mehtods.

```
const messageObservable = Observable;

subscriptions(){
        message$: messageObservable
    },
    created(){
        message$.
        fromEvent(document.querySelector('textarea'), 'input').
        map(event => event.target.value).
        debounceTime(500).
        distinctUntilChanged().
        subscribe({
                next: function(value) {
                    console.log(value);
                }
            });
    },
```

Comment: fromEvent is a static method, how could you use it on message$?

Comment: THe tutorials that I have seen operate like what I have\

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the tutorial you are following along is out to date. This `imports` are not longer working. ([see changelog](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md))

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
```

The latest and stable version is `rxjs6`. This is the correct way of using it:

```
import { fromEvent, map, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

...

created() {
  message$.
    pipe(
      map(event => event.target.value),
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged()
  ).subscribe(console.log);
}
```

**I am guessing this is how you want to use fromEvent**.

```
created() {
      message$.
        pipe(
          switchMap(val => fromEvent(document.querySelector('textarea'), 'input'))
          map(event => event.target.value),
          debounceTime(500),
          distinctUntilChanged()
      ).subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Comment: What does pipe do I don't remember having to do it like this when I first learned RXJS

Comment: They just receive an Observable as an argument and return an Observable. This is the new way of performing operation over Observables in rxjs. See this doc, https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md.